# DynamoDB atomic counter that rolls over

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I would like to have an atomic counter that resets back to 1 when it hits a threshold for a location (key).
I can increment without issues, but would like it to be atomic on the roll over if possible.

CF has:

```
    "TicketNumberTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "location",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "location",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
        "TableName": { "Fn::Join": [ "", [ "ticketnumber", { "Ref": "env" } ] ] }
      }
    }
```

How would I add into this update call a roll over to 1 if the counter is over 100 (for example)?

Currently my code is:

```
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.TICKET_NUMBER_TABLE,
    Key: {
      'location': {
        'S': 'somewhere'
      }
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'ADD #counter :inc',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#counter': 'counter'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
      ':inc': {
        'N': '1'
      }
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
  }
```

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way. Maybe just consider the value as the tracked value mod 100. :)

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! Thanks for that.

Comment: I agree with @hunterhacker and also think they should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a way. Maybe just consider the value as the tracked value mod 100. :)